# When did Harry get the leather coat?

Tags: books, the-dresden-files, jim-butcher

In the Dresden Files books, at some point Harry trades in his canvas duster for a leather duster?  Which book did this happen in and why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

He was given it by Susan in preparation for the climactic battle in *Fool Moon*.

> I stood up, but Susan grabbed my wrist. "Harry," she said. "Wait a minute." She knelt down by the bag and drew out a heavy box, flat and broad. "I was going to give it to you for your birthday. But I thought you could use it."
>
> I tilted my head and took the box in hand. It was heavy. "What is it?" I asked her.
>
> "Just open it, dummy," she answered, smiling up at me. I did, and inside was the smell of soft, worked leather, sensuous and thick, wrapped up in translucent paper. I tossed the lid aside, took the paper off, and found dark leather, new and matte black, hardly casting back the light. I took it out of the box, and it unfolded into a heavy, long coat, like my own duster in design, even to the mantle around the shoulders and arms, but all made of the finer material.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just add that he gets *another* leather jacket in Cold Days, right before the climactic series of battles.  This time he's given it by Molly.

> Who, um ... sort of stole the money from White Court vampires to buy it